# App Crashes when calling FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken())

Tags: java, android, firebase

In my `MainActivity` class, my app crashes when trying to call `FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("global");` and   `Log.i(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());` also trying the console in Firebase i cannot receive any notification.

Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

checkPlayServices(); 

FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("global");
Log.i(TAG, "InstanceID token: " + FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken());

}
}
```

Also i wanted to know is it important to subscribe on topics?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bad, I forgot to do [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk)  steps, i already fixed the error. I needed to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` in my app graddle and add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in my project level gradle. It works fine now.